# How to handle OutOfMemory Exception while creating a Bitmap from image fetched from SQLite DB?

Tags: android, image, sqlite, bitmap, out-of-memory

I have primarily a question,Can I set a byte[] as image in ImageView without converting back to Bitmap?

The OOM error is thrown when I decode the byte[] to bitmap and I am seeing this happening for images of 300 KB even. I have opted to use `BitmapFactory.options` (inSampleSize) to scale the image to avoid the exception.

But this alters the dimension (width especially) of my image which looks so bad in my application. Is there anyway to fetch the original image from DB without scaling or altering the image (of course without the risk of OOM error)??

Any help is appreciated..!!

Thanks in Advance.

Code that troubles:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap ImageBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        //checking if the image is too large we can resize it small in order to avoid Out of Memory error from the decodeStream method.
        if(showfullImage(options.outWidth) && !isExternal)
        {
            options.inSampleSize = 2;
        }
        imageStream.close();
        imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray);
        ImageBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        return ImageBmp;
```

Comment: first of all: don't store images in the db, second: use the filesystem where you can store the original full sized image and its thumbnail

Comment: Got it..But requirement demands...@pskink Is there anyway to deal with images in DB??

Comment: see http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html

Comment: Thanks for the link .... But the thing is I do not find a performance problem when retrieving from DB but I face trouble while converting it back to Bitmap... Is there a way to Optimize that part?

Comment: how big are they? and how many of them you show at one time?

Comment: They are below 1mb<... Also I just need to show one of it at a time in an imageview..

Comment: so it should work ok, unless you have some other Bitmaps hanging around which make memory leaks

Comment: Find my code in the Question @pskink

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82823/discussion-between-kannan-sjd-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink Thanks for your timely help... the problem was with my heap memory exceeded due to another memory leak and I have resolved that. Also I have set the LargeHeap attribute to {True}. Now everything seems to work fine

Comment: so i was right about some "hanging" Bitmaps or other objects...

Comment: Yes, You are correct... ;) @pskink